# Specifying which value to return in lisp

Tags: parsing, io, lisp

I'm completely new to lisp programming.  I need to write a program for a class that reads words out of an xml doc.  Anyway, I wrote this function that takes an array (word) and a file stream (in).  I want it to loop until it reaches a #\space in the stream while adding each collected character to the word.  I then want the word returned.  I'm sure I'm doing many things wrong, but here's the method I have.  I'm fairly certain that the return function at the end is completely out of place:

```
(defun get-string (in word)
  (loop for char = (read-char in nil)
      while (not (char= char #\space))
      do(vector-push-extend char word))
  (return word))
```

Now I have anther issue.  The loop keeps on looking for characters after it finds a space and I get a bunch of nils.  Also, I need to stop on newlines, but am not sure how to.  I tied this, but it just reads every character.

```
(defun get-string (in word)
 (loop for char = (read-char in nil)
      while (not (or (char= char #\space)
                (char= char #\newline)))
    do(print char))
  word)
```

The print char is in there because I'm not very good at understanding the debugger and want to see what characters I'm reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`word` is a variable and a variable evaluates to its value. In a `DEFUN` body, the last expression's value is returned. So the return around `word` is not needed, if you want to return the value of `word`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit `return` statement. That's only for early returns from lexical scopes. So this version works:

```
(defun get-string (in word)
  (loop for char = (read-char in nil)
        while (not (char= char #\space))
        do (vector-push-extend char word))
  word)
```

But I'm wondering about another thing in your function: Is the word parameter meant to get passed empty arrays only? You don't need to pass buffers around to do string handling, Lisp isn't C. Thanks to automatic memory management, you can just create strings in a function and return them.

Therefore, I would write a function for reading space-delimited words from a stream like this:

```
(defun read-word (&optional (stream *standard-input*))
  (with-output-to-string (word)
   (loop for char = (read-char stream nil)
         while (and char
                    (char/= char #\Space)
                    (char/= char #\Newline))
         do (write-char char word))))
```

Regarding your newly added question: I don't see why your loop shouldn't stop when you've read a space. OTOH, what you're not checking for is a NIL, the return value in case of an EOF. That's why I've added the first condition (just `char`) in the `and` in my own function for.

EDIT: replaced my own function with one that doesn't use its own line buffering, because that's fragile, too complicated, and unnecessary here. Also, added an answer to the extended question.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean, but I'm passing the stream around because I'm reading words out of a file.  Before this function I use another to skip past any text wrapped in <>, then I pass the stream on to the get-word function which pulls strings in between the xml tags.

Comment: Do you thing the closure is a good idea? How about reading from to different streams? Thread safety? The LET also prevents the DEFUN from being a top-level construct, which it usually should be.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I've copied the code from a program in which it worked well. But you're probably right that there are too many cases in which it will cause problems, therefore I will replace it in a edit.

Comment: @webhound: I didn't mean the stream argument. The function I presented takes a stream argument, too. I meant the argument `word`. Do you actually want to append the new characters to the previous contents of this array, or are you just passing in a (supposedly emtpy) buffer?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: There was actually a character already appended to word when it was passed in.  It was an ugly program. I'm still trying to get used to lisp.  I've only been working with it for about a week.  Anyway, I'm scrapping the original program and trying a different approach.

Comment: @webhound: `with-output-to-string` can take an old string to append to as an optional argument. But since you're going to try a different approach, I'd recomment using an XML library, like CXML: http://www.cliki.net/CXML